# Defining a Cosmos synthetic partition key in yaml

Tags: yaml, azure-cosmosdb

I am setting up Azure Cosmos DB with a yaml file and at the moment I am setting the partition key path to /serialNumber. I now want to use a synthetic partition key of tenantId and serialNumber but can't find any examples of how to define a synthetic key in yaml. Can someone show me an example of how this can be done?

my yaml is:

```
 az cosmosdb sql container create -g $resourceGroup -a $cosmosAccountName -d $databaseName -n $containerName `
        --partition-key-path "/serialNumber" | Out-Null ; Test-Exit
```

The object I am saving has the following fields:

```
Guid tenantid;
string serialNumber;
List<Users> users;
```

Comment: Can't you just name your partition key attribute as `_partitionKey` and when the time comes for saving the value, you create a string combining `tenantId` and `serialNumber` and save that?

Comment: @GauravMantri, if that is the way it's supposed to be done then that's what I'll do. Seems to be a shortage of c# code examples, just lots of json.

Comment: Please see if this link helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the best practices in Cosmos DB, for partition key you should choose an attribute that is likely to have many distinct values so that you can avoid situations like creating hot partitions.

If that attribute is not available in your data, then Cosmos DB team recommends creating a `synthetic partition key`. When they talk about `synthetic partition key`, what they mean really is the data that will be stored in that partition key. You could name that partition key attribute as anything that you like.

Taking your scenario, this is how your data looks like:

```
{
    "tenantId": "some guid",
    "serialNumber": "some string",
    "users": [
        //Array of users
    ]
}
```

Now if you think that neither `tenantId` nor `serialNumber` are good choices for partition key, you can add another attribute in your document (say `_partitionKey`) and set its value to `tenantId Value + serialNumber value`. In this case, `_partitionKey` will be the synthetic partition key.

Your resulting document would look something like the following:

```
{
    "tenantId": "some guid",
    "serialNumber": "some string",
    "_partitionKey": "<tenantId value>_<serialNumber value>"
    "users": [
        //Array of users
    ]
}
```

Your YAML would look something like:

```
az cosmosdb sql container create -g $resourceGroup -a $cosmosAccountName -d $databaseName -n $containerName `
        --partition-key-path "/_partitionKey" | Out-Null ; Test-Exit
```

For more information on synthetic partition key, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys.